# Format options setting collapses lines

Tags: formatting, word-processing

I set up this nifty custom function to help me use Vim for word processing:

```
func! WordProcessorMode()
    setlocal formatoptions=ant
    setlocal textwidth=60
    setlocal wrapmargin=0
endfu
com! WP call WordProcessorMode()
```

However, when I use this mode, I find that unless I leave an empty line between two paragraphs, the two adjacent lines are automatically joined together, e.g.:

```
New Hampshire Spanks the Elites
Panic Sets In On Clinton Campaign
Some Sage Advice for Hillary Clinton
```

becomes

```
New Hampshire Spanks the Elites Panic Sets in on Clinton Campaign Some Sage Advice for Hillary Clinton
```

Of course, most of the time it's good practice to format your prose tidily, but sometimes (with numbered lists and whatnot) I would like to have the freedom to insert adjacent non-collapsed lines. Is it possible to alter my function to prevent this sort of behavior, or alternatively suspend it temporarily somehow so I can insert a numbered list?

Answer (score 3):

I also use vim for a lot of word processing/prose, and I format as I go, rather than having a catch-all command that formats all your text at once. By manually formatting as I go, I implicitly solve the problem you describe. I'm not sure if this fits your workflow, but I'll describe it below:

I use this mapping:

```
" Easy line wrapping/formatting
imap gq <C-G>u<ESC>gw}
```

Which I invoke whenever I want to leave insert mode after typing out text that I wish to format.

This mapping performs the following actions:

`<C-G>u` Manually create an undo-block, so we can unformat the text if we don't like it;

`<ESC>` Leave insert mode;

`gw}` Format to the end of the paragraph. You can change `}` to whatever motion you prefer. (I format as I go along, so I only format from my current position to the end of the paragraph, which works well if I assume the previous text in the paragraph is formatted correctly.)

So as you're typing out

```
New Hampshire Spanks the Elites
Panic Sets In On Clinton Campaign
Some Sage Advice for Hillary Clinton
```

You simply don't use the mapping to leave insert mode. If you're typing out something that you DO want to format however; use the mapping to leave insert mode, and everything's done for you.

EG a long series of text input:

```
Streaming video is becoming a larger and more important proportion of internet traffic with each passing year. Video data is projected to take up 80\% of consumer internet traffic in 2019, with over 70\% of that being delivered via commercial Content Delivery Networks
```

gets formatted into the following when I leave insert mode:

```
Streaming video is becoming a larger and more important proportion of
internet traffic with each passing year. Video data is projected to take up
80\% of consumer internet traffic in 2019, with over 70\% of that being
delivered via commercial Content Delivery Networks
```

And if I want to make an edit to some point of the paragraph:

```
Streaming video is REALLY COOL AND I LIKE IT SO MUCH AND SO DOES EVERYONE ELSE AND THAT'S WHY IT'S becoming a larger and more important proportion of
internet traffic with each passing year. Video data is projected to take up
80\% of consumer internet traffic in 2019, with over 70\% of that being
delivered via commercial Content Delivery Networks
```

This gets nicely formatted into the following as well, when I leave insert mode:

```
Streaming video is REALLY COOL AND I LIKE IT SO MUCH AND SO DOES EVERYONE
ELSE AND THAT'S WHY IT'S becoming a larger and more important proportion of
internet traffic with each passing year. Video data is projected to take up
80\% of consumer internet traffic in 2019, with over 70\% of that being
delivered via commercial Content Delivery Networks
```

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion. Perhaps I will go down that route. Preferably, though, I'd like something that would let me focus more on the text and have to do less formatting (minimal though this is; I'll concede that).

Comment: Yeah, this was about as unintrusive as I could get it, while still allowing me to type in tables/specially formatted text as I like. I figured if you have to leave insert mode anyways, might as well hook a mapping onto leaving insert mode.